# Recommended way of sending response object in body for errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a Custom response class

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Getter @Setter @ToString @Builder @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class WrapperRestResponse {

    @ApiModelProperty(name="responseCode",notes = "http status response codes")
    private Integer responseCode;
    @ApiModelProperty(name="status",notes = "Success|Failure")
    private String status;
    @ApiModelProperty(name="errors",notes = "In case of Failure, it will contains error messages")
    private List<String> errors;
    @ApiModelProperty(name="body",notes = "In case of Success, it will return object")
    private Object body;
}
```

A Util function for errors that uses this response class:

```java
public static WrapperRestResponse getErrorResponse(HttpStatus statusCode, String ... errors){
        return WrapperRestResponse.builder()
                .status(WrapperConstant.FAILURE)
                .responseCode(statusCode.value())
                .errors(Arrays.asList(errors))
                .build();
    }
```

And my controller sends response like this:

```java
@PostMapping
@ApiOperation(value = "Register", notes = "Register")
public WrapperRestResponse register(@RequestBody DTO request) {
        try {
            return Util.getSuccessResponse(HttpStatus.CREATED, Service.create(request));
        } catch (ImproperDataException e) {
           return Util.getErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Util.getErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**The problem:**
When the code raises a bad request error response, the status code is still 200. The response looks like the following ( NOTE: responseCode is 400 but statusCode is 200:

```
{
    "text": "{\"responseCode\":400,\"status\":\"Failure\",\"errors\":[\"The following need to be registered before logging usage against them:[data1]\"]}",
    "statusText": "OK",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "status": 200,
    "statusType": 2,
    
    
    "type": "application/json",
    "charset": "utf-8",
    "links": {},
    "body": {
        "responseCode": 400,
        "status": "Failure",
        "errors": [
            "The following need to be registered before logging usage against them:[data1]"
        ]
    }
}
```

What would be an elegant Spring way to handle such exceptions and match the `statusCode` and `responseCode`?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question because I don't use Spring (or Java), but in my experience, unless you are going with a "by-the-book" REST API, I'd rather return 200 on the http status code and whatever error code inside the object: that way you can distinguish that "at least the error is coming from your API" (this is controversial, but many big names do it like that on their web APIs)

Comment: @Jcl, With this approach, I find it a bit unintuitive to be checking for status code and this response code on the UI. Is that a standard practice?

Comment: not really "standard", although some do (I belive for example Facebook Graph API always returns 200, you check error codes in the payload, not in http)...  I've had problems where the infrastructure in the middle of my API (load balancers, reverse proxies, etc.) could give error codes and I couldn't know if they came from my API or not, specially for http status codes that don't include a payload... for example, a 404: does it come from my API not finding my resource or the reverse proxy not finding my API? I ended up using 200 for anything on my API and checking errors on the payload

Comment: Btw, that has the benefit of also not restricting yourself to standard http-status codes (which are limited and not always very clear)... there are however instances where browser-recognized http status codes are unavoidable (for example, 304 for `If-None-Match` cache hits if you want the browser to load the cached data, etc.), but apart from those

Answer (score -1):

Why you are not using Spring's inbuilt class `ResponseEntity` like below

```
@PostMapping
@ApiOperation(value = "Register", notes = "Register")
public ResponseEntity<Object> register(@RequestBody DTO request) {
    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(Service.create(request),HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (ImproperDataException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(Arrays.asList(e.getMessage()),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(Arrays.asList(e.getMessage()),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```